# How do I clean up the used memory of the Viewpoint XLSX toolkit in LabVIEW?

Tags: .net, excel, labview

I'm using the Viewpoint XLSX toolkit in LabVIEW 2018. This Viewpoint XLSX toolkit is a .NET dll what is called by LabVIEW.

I see this is using up a lot of the computers memory. Is there a function to call to clean up the no longer needed memory after the XLSX file is closed?

If I just open a XLSX file of 30MB in Excel 365 ProPlus. This takes 160MB of the computers memory (incl. the Excel executable)

Now I open the same file in LabVIEW 2018. With a test VI shown in the link.
[Picture of the VI code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt8yO.png)

Just open LabVIEW and the VI takes 200MB. (VI not running yet)
Breakpoint 1: After XLSX Open Workbook there is 660MB used.
Breakpoint 2, 3, 4: List Worksheets, Open and close Worksheet at all three points there is 820MB used.
Breakpoint 5: After/During Saving the Workbook there is 1145MB used.
After closing the workbook (and ending the VI run) there is still 745MB used.

All this is just with a 30MB XLSX file.
What function can I call to cleanup the memory?

It looks like Excel use about 90MB of memory to hold the 30MB file. But the Viewpoint Toolkit seems to use 900MB of memory to hold the same 30MB file in memory. How can I prevent the Viewpoint XLSX toolkit from using so much memory?

I tried to look in the property and invoke node to find some calls related to this. I also tried to run the Request Deallocation VI, but both are not helping.

Comment: Have you gotten in touch with the folks at Viewpoint Systems? What did they say?

Comment: I'm in touch with the folks from Viewpoint Systems. First thing we found is that I still had the V1.2.1.1 of the toolkit installed. It seems I needed to force JKI VIPM to check for the package repositories for updates. Now V1.2.1.3 is in my list and installed. But this didn't solve the memory usage.

Comment: Unless you're able to edit the VIs they provided, I don't think there's much that can be done about memory usage--and even then, the cause may be in the dll file. Does the memory usage go down after completely closing out of LabVIEW?

Comment: Most of the VIs Viewpoint provide are readable. You get a .NET reference after opening a XLSX file, that is interfaced with property and invoke node calls. I'm also afraid that it might be in the DLL file, that's not readable for me. After the VI run there is still memory allocated, what will go away after the LabVIEW project is closed. Will that be the time LabVIEW really remove the DLL from it's memory.

Comment: If I were you, I'd pore over what code I could get into and see if they're properly closing .net references. Failing that, it's always possible their application is simply memory-heavy.